# Compile errors when including GameLayer.h in Cocos2D project with Box2D

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

so i have the following code in a file called mainMenu:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:[GameLayer scene]];
```

and I have `#import "GameLayer.h"`. GameLayer has cocos2d, box2d, GLES-Render included in the `.h` header file.

so whenever I include GameLayer in the mainMenu file (`.m`) and try to build the app, it fails returning around 360 errors all about b2d (b2settings, b2math etc). anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong??

NOTE the mainMenu code works perfectly fine without including the GameLayer, and so does GameLayer without mainMenu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change Main Menu's extension to .mm. This makes it an Objective-C++ file, which is needed, because box2d is in C++.

Comment: No problem - I've forgotten this on several occasions before as well!